# In-Sample vs. Out-of-Sample One-Step Ahead Forecasts

Tags: forecasting, out-of-sample, in-sample

I'm fairly new to forecasting but I find all of this quote fascinating and hope to learn something from all of you.

I have 500 observations and I'm tasked with the following: "compute recursive (expanding window) in-sample one-step ahead forecasts and recursive (expanding window) out-of-sample one-step ahead forecasts." I then test these two forecasts using RMSE. My model is a simple autoregressive process with drift.

Let's start with the second task, the out-of-sample forecasts. This is what I've done:

1. Estimated my model with the first 400 observations and obtained the relevant estimators.
2. Predicted the value of observation 401 with the above estimators.
3. Stored the squared error of the difference between the actual 401st observation and the predicted 401st observation.
4. Re-estimate the model but now with 401 observations, obtaining new estimators.
5. Predicted the value of observation 402 with the new estimators, store the squared error, and then reestimate the model again and obtain new estimators.
6. Repeat all the way up to the 500th observation.

I believe this is what the task asks for but as some of the terminology is new to me I'm not 100% sure. Now, for the first part of the task, I'm quite confused as to where any type of recursiveness could come in. From what I understand, this should be my process:

1. Estimate my model with all 500 observations and obtain the relevant estimators.
2. Predict observation 401 with the above estimators.
3. Calculate the squared error of the difference between the actual 401st observation and the predicted 401st observation.
4. Repeat the above for observations 402 to 500.

Because it's in-sample forecasting, I estimate the model with all 500 observations and then "re-test" the final 100 observations as validation. What in the question am I misunderstanding?

Thanks!

Comment: What you are asking is called as the rolling origin forecast evaluation. There is a blog by Rob Hyndman which explains this detail. Here is the [link](http://robjhyndman.com/hyndsight/rolling-forecasts/) I implemented something similar to your second task which is called as "Multi-​​step fore­casts with re-​​estimation" in the link. I'm not sure if I'm following the first part of the task. Hope this heps